# Broadcast receiver inside activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm a newbie of Android. I would like to know from a more experienced programmer if I'm doing well. Inside an activity I declare a BroadcastReceiver in this way:

```
private BroadcastReceiver locationUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
                    //Do something
        }
    }
};
```

I register the receiver onResume() and unregister it onPause(). Could I run in memory leaks?
If no, would be the same if I declare a non-static inner class that extends BroadcastReceiver and I used it inside the activity, always registering and unregistering as before? (I suppose that in this way I control its life-cycle).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Doing so will not cause any memory leak.

Comment: Thank you, you mean in both cases?

Comment: Yep, with inner class it will be the same. For each onResume, onPause will be called once the activity will go to the background (temporarily or when the activity will be destroyed), you can know for sure that you're logic is fine.

Comment: It's better to register it onStart() instead of onResume(). You should avoid as much as you can code inside onResume/onPause to avoid sluggish transitions between applications.